# How to access fontawesome icon via components in angular6

Tags: angular, angular-material-6, angular-fontawesome

I fount Nested sidenav with icon's stackbiltz here
[Nested sidenav](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-nested-sidenav-menu?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Here they used mat-icon to display icon display in sidenav menu, For my project most of icon not available in mat-icon, so i planned to use font-awesome icon. I need help to access font-awesome icon via component. I need help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Font Awesome now has an official Angular component that’s available for all who want to easily use their icons in projects. 
follow steps provided here 
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/angular

All the best. Let us know in case of any query.

Comment: I have installed angular font-awesome in my project also i can also able to display to call that class i.e <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i> with in any span or div or mat-icon. On that stackbiltz having one property iconName in nav-item.ts file in this case just we past mat-icon name like "home" or "delete" it will work. My question i need to font-awesome icon like this i expected.